# border-top Html2Pdf bug

Tags: css, html2pdf

When we have a property `border-collapse: collapse;` on a table the property  `border-top`  doesn't work After converting it to `pdf`. Like this:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
table td {
  border-top: 2px solid #AAAAAA; 
}
```

Comment: what i do to fix it

Comment: Browsers have a debugging console. You probably need to do a little more research and then explain what "does not work" means. Assume no one has the time to figure out what you think should be obvious. See [ask].

Comment: Your sample code does not contain `border-top`.